# Node/Express respond only to specific domains

Tags: node.js, express

Is it possible to bind different hostnames to different Express instances?

**For example:** example.com would direct to one NodeJs/Express instance running on port 80 and example.org would direct to another NodeJs/Express instance running on port 80.

If this is completely confusing, think of how IIS is capable of binding specific host headers to specific IIS websites.

Comment: I don't think so. The best option is to use nginx, Apache or another web server to reverse proxy requests from specific hostnames to Node.js apps running on different ports.

Comment: You can use nginx to help sort out multiple domains running on the same IP, but you can't have multiple Express instances on the same server listening to the same port because only one instance can listen to a given port.  You can use one Express instance and two routers (one for each domain).  Or use nginx to forward the port 80 requests from each domain to a different Express instance running on different ports.

Comment: ^ do that, use nginx to listen to port 80, then route it back to two different Node instances listening on different ports running with Forever.

Comment: Thanks for the rapid helpful response.   Is there a specific benefit to nginx vs Apache?    Or is it completely a Chevy vs Ford, Coke vs Pepsi comparison?    I have no plans to run PHP, etc. on this particular server.   It would be hosting MEAN-stack applications and static resources.

Comment: Use nginx - Apache blocks when it hits a (low) max number of concurrent connections, effectively throttling Node.  Nginx doesn't.